# Facebook comments, empty div underneath

Tags: facebook, comments

occasionally several empty div tags are created under the comments block.
They all have an id like "bootloader_****" and takes up space.

Why is this happening?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is coming from the Facebook parser.  Unfortunately, you won't have any control over that.

Actually, you could possibly (not sure as I've not tested it) use jQuery in order to remove any `bootloader_` tags.

Comment: They recently changed the `fb:comments` to include the `Like` button.  So, it could be.

Comment: I agree, but this is just one small thing to get used to when developing something to work with Facebook ;o)